# Every other SQL Server deployment fails due to access denied on Kubernetes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am deploying a SQL Server 2019 to Kubernetes with the following manifest:

```
apiVersion : apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sql 
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: 'sql'
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sql 
    spec:
      hostname: sql-dev
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 10001
      initContainers:
      - name: volume-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 10001:0 /var/opt/mssql"]
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/var/opt/mssql"
          name: mssqldb
      containers:
        - name: sql 
          image: localhost:32000/sql:dev-latest
          env:
          - name: MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mssql
                key: SA_PASSWORD
          - name: ACCEPT_EULA
            value: "Y"
          ports:
          - containerPort: 1433
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 2Gi
              cpu: 1
          volumeMounts:
          - name: mssqldb
            mountPath: /var/opt/mssql
      volumes:
      - name: mssqldb
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: sqldev-pvc
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: sql-svc
spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 1433
      targetPort: 1433
      nodePort: 31113
    selector:
        app: sql
```

And this is the pv/pvc manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: sqldev-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes: 
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: sql
  hostPath:
    path: /usr/sql
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: sqldev-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: sql
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

If the deployment is not present on the Cluster yet, the deployment itself works and the server is available.
The next deployment fails with the following message:

> 2021-01-20 12:02:34.98 Server      Error: 17113, Severity: 16, State:
> 2021-01-20 12:02:34.98 Server      Error 5(Access is denied.) occurred while opening file '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf' to obtain
> configuration information at startup. An invalid startup option might
> have caused the error. Verify your startup options, and correct or
> remove them if necessary.

Doing another deployment or simply restarting it with `kubectl rollout restart deployment/sql` comes up fine, while the next one fails again.
The pattern is a consistent good - bad - good - bad - ...

Plese explain why this is happening and how I can resolve this.

**Update:** Apparently one instance of mssql exclusively locks the database files - which makes total sense. You don't want 2 instances of `brain` going haywire on your sole instance of `childhood memories`.

So what I think is happening is:

1. Instance `A` exists and is up and running
2. Instance `B` deployment starts and wants to access the same volume as `A`
3. Only when `B` is created, `A` is being terminated with a grace period of 30 seconds
4. `B` is trying to access the mdf, while it is still being excklusively locked by and to `A` currently being terminated.

I have a crude solution involving a `sleep 30` bash script before initializing mssql inside the pod, but right now I want to investigate, if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a very complex question with two topics. Kubernetes would be probably better suited for the Server Fault site. But database issues are fine here. I'm not sure if we have anybody in the community that has a good enough understanding of both topics. Quoting Highlander ***There can be only one!*** - the **master** database can only be installed once per instance. If you are using two SQL SRV installations with the same location, then it will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first approach to solve this was to delay the boot up time of mssql until the previous pod was terminated using a bash loop:

```
echo "Waiting 35 seconds grace period."
for i in {0..35}
do
   sleep 1
   echo "$i seconds waited"
done
```

While this technically solved the problem, it isn't very elegant. If the grace period of the pod is changed to someting > 35 seconds, this will need to be changed too.

Changing the deployment strategy from its implicit default `RollingUpdate` to `Recreate`, did the trick to. The effect is, that the previous pod is being terminated before the new one is spun up.

```
apiVersion : apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sql 
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: 'sql'
  strategy:
      type: Recreate
```

Documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#recreate-deployment